# Kibana and large results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When I run a search in Kibana that returns several hundred documents I am getting an error that the results are too large.  The actual error message is below:

> Can't store an async search response larger than [10485760] bytes. This limit can be set by changing the `[search.max_async_search_response_size]` setting.

This does NOT seem to be something I can change in the UI  In fact, just clicking on this index in Kibana Discover and no search, I get this error.  If run a search that just brings back a few (ten's of doc's) I will get results as expected, but otherwise I am getting these kinds of results.

My index has about 300K documents and most a relatively small, but around 40 to 50 fields (mostly file metadata and some other metadata type fields).

Does any one have any advice on this?

Comment: Where do you run this search? In Dev Tools or Discover? What do you need so many results for, would an export be sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
PUT _cluster/settings -d '{
  "persistent": {
    "search.max_async_search_response_size": "50mb"
  }
}'
```

This parameter could be apply from kibana dev-tools

doc parameter description:

```
By default, Elasticsearch doesn’t allow to store an async search response larger than 10Mb, and an attempt to do this results in an error. The maximum allowed size for a stored async search response can be set by changing the search.max_async_search_response_size cluster level setting.
```

Comment: your answer is good, but your json has an extra space in "search.max_async_search_response_size ": "50mb"

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running elasticsearch and kibana using docker compose where elastic search is running at localhost:9200. The following worked for me from command line

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"persistent\": { \"search.max_async_search_response_size\": \"50mb\"}}"
```